# How to set the name of a channel from the guildMemberAdd event?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a voice channel which displays the number of members on my server, however I can't seem to be able to get the ID of the channel to change it. I have this code in the `guildMemberAdd` event:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'factions');
  channel.send(`Welcome to the server, <@${member.id}>! Make sure to check out <#757221255198802051> and <#757221255198802051>!`);
  
  const serverCount = (bot.guilds.cache.get(member.guild.id).memberCount);
  member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === "Server Count:").setName(`Server Count: ${serverCount}`);
});
```

This all works apart from the last line because `member.guild.channels.find is not a function`. I know that I need to do `channel.setName` but I am not sure how to get the channel to set the name of from the `member` object that is passed into the `guildMemberAdd` event.

Comment: Remember to use the `cache` property. `member.guild.channels.cache.find()`. Also, if the channel name displays the number of users on the server, it's never going to display `Server Count:`. I would say using the `startsWith()` function is a better bet than `===`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot 2 things, `cache` and the `startsWith()` function. To fix your problem:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'factions');
  channel.send(`Welcome to the server, <@${member.id}>! Make sure to check out <#757221255198802051> and <#757221255198802051>!`);
  
  const serverCount = member.guild.memberCount;
  member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name.startsWith("Server Count: ")).setName(`Server Count: ${serverCount}`);
});
```